# Navigation drawer use at another activity only, not in main activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I have a project containing different activities like: main activity, signup activity, login activity and track activity.   Now I want to create another activity which will contain navigation drawer. And the point is "I don't want to use navigation drawer at any other activity".

All the example so far I found at searching @ net provide example using main activity.  But I don't want to use navigation bar at main activity.

Comment: You can add `NavigationDrawer`s seperately but if you want to add `NavigationDrawer` automatically when creating new Activities. create `BaseActivity` which has `NavigationDrawer` and extend it when creating new Activities. Look **Google IOSched 15'** `BaseActivity`: [BaseActivity](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/BaseActivity.java) . And in your question you dont want to use NavigationDrawer or NavigationBar in your new Activity?

Comment: @ Yasin,   Thanks for the info.   I want to say that I will use navigation bar just with a specific activity which don't create yet, but not in main activity or any existing activity in my project

Comment: according to your comment NavigationBar is like that : [NavigationBar](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=android+navigation+bar&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG3pTygu7NAhWBqCwKHTzPBJoQ_AUICCgB&biw=1745&bih=868#imgrc=v189uGIJYaqARM%3A) if you sure hiding it i can help you ?

Comment: Sorry it will be navigation drawer not bar.

Comment: if you dont want to add navigation drawer jsut dont add then when creating new activity ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, follow these steps,

```
 1. Right click on app.
 2. new -> activity -> navigationDrawerActivity
```

this way only your new activity will have navigation drawer.